# Double Newman Projections

Tags: organic-chemistry, cyclohexane

How do I draw a double Newman projection for cyclohexane? Which bond(s) do I sight down?

[image]

From what I understand, if we have 1-methylcyclohexane, we sight C1-C2 and C5-C4, as shown in my attempt below:

[image]

Would this be correct? I wish to achieve level 4!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that -Cl and -CH(CH3)2 are on equatorial positions(The slant lines suggest that)

And the -H is on axial position(The perfectly vertical line suggest that)

Note that it is not just a coincidence, rather it is intentional. I think it would suffice further.